# Can one Sidekiq instance process multiple queues from multiple applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I can run multiple sidekiq processes each one process queues for a specific Rails application.

But if I have 10 applications then it will be always running 10 Sidekiq processes each one consuming memory.

How to run only one Sidekiq process which will serve multiple applications?

Comment: Nope, can't be done.  You are better off making one app which is multi-tenant using [Apartment](https://github.com/influitive/apartment) and using Sidekiq with that one app.

Comment: I am thinking of using sucker_punch gem.

Comment: while booting, `sidekiq` instantiate your current `app` and executes the tasks on behalf of your application.. so same `sidekiq` instance for multiple application sounds impossible. You can decrease the number of `worker` processes though to save memory